# insert data in a std::map

Tags: c++, stdmap

I have the following container:

```
map<int,string,string> data;
```

I have been trying to store information in that map using the following codes(one at a time) but none of them works.

```
data.insert( m, f, l );
data.insert( map<int,string,string>(m, f, l) );
data.insert( pair<int,string,string>(m, f, l) );
```

Anyone has any idea how to store data in a std::map?

Thank you

Comment: `map<int,string,string> data;` isn't a thing. `std::string` cannot be used as comparison functor type. Read the [reference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) please.

Comment: `std::map<int,string,string>` is invalid, you can only specify one key type and one value type.

Comment: I know it is not a thing since it did not work.

Comment: "Anyone has any idea how to store data in a std::map?" doesn't seem a good question.

Comment: You mean you want `map<int, std::pair<string,string> > data;` or `map<std::pair<int,string>,string> data;`?

Comment: @zeeks If you got the correct answer, why not post it as answer?

Comment: @MikeCAT I want the first one.

Comment: @MikeCAT How do I store data for the first one?

Comment: @zeeks fix your question if you want `std::map<int, std::pair<std::string,std::string>>` then say so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write

```
map<int, std::pair<string, string> > data;
```

to create a map (`std::map`) whose key is one `int` and data is two `string`s.

To insert data, you can write

```
data.insert(std::make_pair<int, std::pair<string, string> >(m, std::make_pair<string, string>(f, l));
```

or more simply

```
data[m] = std::make_pair<string, string>(f, l);
```

Full example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

using std::map;
using std::string;

int main(void) {
    map<int, std::pair<string, string> > data;
    int m;
    string f, l;

    // insert data
    m = 20; f = "hoge"; l = "fuga";
    data.insert(std::pair<int, std::pair<string, string> >(m, std::pair<string, string>(f, l)));
    m = 10; f = "foo"; l = "bar";
    data[m] = std::pair<string, string>(f, l);

    // display data
    for (map<int, std::pair<string, string> >::iterator it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); it++) {
        std::cout << it->first << " -> " << it->second.first << ", " << it->second.second << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```